# How to sample an image at lesser resolution at outside pixels than inside pixels?

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I'm trying to implement an auto encoder(neural network) in which I need to make 32*32 images into patches and give them as input to the network. From each image, it is needed to make 81 patches with a stride of 2 pixels. While getting each patch we need to see an area of 16*16 pixels and the centre 8*8 should be sampled at the original resolution while outer pixels should be sampled at lower resolution making each patch only 112 pixels.

[image]

8*8 center pixels=64 pixels from 64 pixels
and outer pixels = 48 pixels from 96 pixels

How to approach this in python?

I can take the center area as it is, but how can I sample the outer region separately(interpolation etc...)?

Any code sample would be much appreciated!

**INFO:** The method suggested above is in this paper http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~fritz/absps/esann-deep-final.pdf

Comment: You would probably do better sampling each square to both resolutions and then picking your data later.

Comment: @SteveBarnes my doubt is that while sampling(interpolation) outer pixels take some information from inner and vice versa...is that okay in general? I'm not familiar with image processing...

Comment: That is the nature of sampling but it depends on your sampling algorithm.

Comment: @SteveBarnes I do not have any sampling algorithm....I want to use Image library in python....as you said I would crop the center part for one resolution with out any sampling...for outer pixels I'm confused as to how to it in python....I've never done anything like that in python...I'm new to python....so how can I separately sample the outer part? or How can I make the resolution lesser keeping the image size same....then?

Comment: Take a look at PIL - the python image library your quickest option would be to re-sample, i.e. drop the size of, the whole image and then grab the data you need.  The other option would be to use numpy load image and do the same.  You will also need to clarify the format your tiles are expected to be in.